# Can't update application in another country apple store

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I moved to Japan, and I have both the Indonesian and the Japanese application store.

But in Japan, when I tried to update my application, it said "verify your billing information", when I tried to verify and add payment information by adding my VISA credit card (Indonesian card) it said this payment method is not valid in this store, it seems like Japan only accepts the Japanese credit card, it won't accept another visa or master card from another country which seems so weird. I tried all methods, I changed to the Indonesian store, but it keeps detecting that my country/region is Japan, so it keeps rejecting although I changed the store, I think this is because some app that I downloaded is from Japanese store.

If I add a payment method in the Indonesian store, I can add billing information using the visa credit card.

When I update some application that I downloaded from Indonesian store, it working well, but when I tried to update apps that I downloaded from the Japanese store, it got stuck and required me to update the billing information.

So I cannot update any apps that I download from the Japanese app store. And this really sucks, because a lot of applications such as Google Maps not working well, because I can't update them.

And to get a credit card in Japan is so hard, because I need to have long term visa, good history of transactions, etc.

Is the only way to fix this to get a Japanese credit card or to buy another iPhone?

Comment: When moving between countries, the App Store country is not automatically changed for you. The App Store switches to another country only when: 1. You change the country in your Apple ID, or, 2. You create and login with a new Apple ID with a desired country. How did you change the country of App Store?

Comment: The simplest solution for problems like this is to have two separate Apple IDs and switch between them as required by logging-out/in from Settings app → iTunes & App Store. An Apple ID can be easily created "without" specifying any payment information/credit-card, to easily install and use free apps on the App Store.

Comment: yes i made two apple id for indonesia and japan, and i changed my country apple id, but it seem when i try to update, it can detect the store when it is downloaded before. so i tried to changed to indonesia apple id but still when i try t update it, it detect country/region :japan so, it require billing infonrmation , but wont accept visa/master card from indonesia. it seem japan only accept japan's credit card number.

Comment: I would advise you not to change the country of Apple ID which was originally used in Indonesia to Japan. Leave it to (revert it to) Indonesia. Since you changed the country, you are not asked by the App Store to provide a valid payment information for Japan. Since you changed the country, you are automatically redirected to Japanese App Store.

Comment: im not changed my country of apple ID, i made account one country: indonesia, and one japan

Comment: Let's discuss and resolve your issue in chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81212/discussion-between-nimesh-neema-and-vixf

Comment: i joined but cant reply

Comment: Apparently you do not have enough [privileges](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) to talk in chat. Do you have any other medium where we can chat and resolve the issue?

Comment: i dont know , this is so furstrating. i tried many things, but still not resolved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81213/discussion-between-nimesh-neema-and-vixf).

Comment: You really don't need to create 2 apple ID's

Answer (score 2):

This should be very straight forward, I had this issue when I moved from the US to the UK, you need to change the Apple ID country/region, the email with which u used to sign into iTunes should be changed by following these instructions

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201389

You can also delete the Apps purchased from the Indonesian App Store and re-download them when signed in with your Apple ID after changing the region.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on your iphone by switching from the Irish to UK account.

1. Go to Settings
2. Tap on your name at the top of the page
3. Scroll to the bottom of page and sign out
4. Now go to the app store and sign in to the UK account
5. Update all your apps

Once done sign back into your usual account.